# Undefined Index PHP $returnans

Tags: php, function, return, undefined-index

I'm trying to return the answer $returnans but it keeps telling me undefined index in line159. If anyone would be so kind to answer how I can fix this it would be greetly appreciated. Thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['getprices'])){

            $destination_input=$_POST['destination'];
            $travellers_input=$_POST['travellersno'];

            define("CADEST1", 12.00); //destination of uk and europe company a
            define("CADEST2", 18.00); //destination of other regions company a
            define("CBDEST1", 19.00); //destination of uk and europe company b
            define("CBDEST2", 24.00); //destination of other regions company b
            define("CCDEST1", 21.00); //destination of uk and europe company c
            define("CCDEST2", 27.00); //destination of other regions company c


            function companyA($destination_input,$travellers_input)
            {
                if($destination_input=="europe" || $destination_input=="uk")
                {
                    $total1=$travellers_input* CADEST1;
                    $returnans=$travellers_input." Persons at 12.00 to ". $destination_input. " = ". $total1;
                }
                else if($destination_input=="worldwideexcluding" || $destination_input=="worldwideincluding" || $destination_input=="australianewzealand")
                {
                    $total2=$travellers_input* CADEST2;
                    $returnans=$travellers_input." Persons at 18.00 to ". $destination_input. " = ". $total2;
                }

                return $returnans;
            }
            function companyB($destination_input,$travellers_input)
            {

            }
            function companyC($destination_input,$travellers_input)
            {

            }

            echo"<h3>Company A-Quote</h3>";
            $returnans=companyA($travellers_input,$destination_input);
            echo $returnans;
            var_dump($returnans);
```

Comment: what is there at line 159

Comment: can you highlight line 159 in your code above?

Comment: in function `function companyA($destination_input,$travellers_input)` declare first line as  ` $returnans = "dummy"; `  then run it

Comment: @Makesh return $returnans on line 159 in function companyA

Comment: Your code doesnt enter thru `if` or `else if`, so `$returnans` never defined. So you are getting error at `return`

Comment: @Makesh I did it but returned dummy instead of the line that I want it to display...

Comment: @Makesh and how can I fix that to go through if and else if pls and display the line that I want as a return?

Comment: Hoping you are a developer, add some debug/echo statements and identify what and where it went wrong.

Comment: @Makesh actually I'm very green in PHP and still learning. I did some var_dump() here and there but still can't figure it out what is wrong.